# 120K military personnel - The Island

Tags: movie, the-island

In [The Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_%282005_film%29) they state at various stages:

- Agnates - 'spare parts for people' are sold to the general public at the rate of $1,000,000 (1 million) per unit.
- The military has funded the research to the value of 120 *billion* dollars.

One would expect that if the military is funding it, it is to replace body parts for highly trained and very vulnerable military personnel.  Spares for the marines, the pilots, the medics etc.  A BOTE calculation would suggest that even if the military is getting their agnates at the same rate as the public, they would be expecting 120,000 units.

Where were those agnates kept?

The storage units seen in the film, high rise buildings, might have comfortably housed 1,000 each (50 per floor x 20 floors).  But even at 1,000, that means 120 high rise buildings, and far fewer than  that were depicted.  Also, I do not recall seeing any obviously military agnates.  There were supermodels & sports stars, a 'rich guy', a politician..

Comment: It's probably worth it to note that they *funded* research because it would be valuable; that money wasn't necessarily going to the purchase of agnates, but rather the research to make such a thing possible.

Comment: @SocioMatt  I disagree.  The company was already selling Agnates to the general public.  By the time 'research' gets to that stage, the military would've wanted their spoils.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree with SocioMatt. Even if a technology is available, you still can invest into some R&D department to improve it. Here, it would be for stronger body parts, for example. Or whatever the arme needs.

Comment: @Kalissar  So where were the 'stronger body parts' kept?  Where was there **any** sign they had taken this ostensibly working technology in a direction which pleased the people who funded it to the tune of $120 billion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failing the appearance of a better explanation, I am putting it down to:  A plot hole in a movie full of plot holes.

Better answers will still be accepted.

So I think I'm going to sit back, skip the boring bits till everybody gets violent, and ignore those plot holes.  Enjoy the action & fast things.  :)